# InfluxDB - Timestamp don't seem to be timestamps

Tags: time, influxdb

I have InfluxDB records that look like this:

```
Some_Measurement:
---------------------
time         field       value
-----        ------      -----
1630686612   myfieldA    123
1630686612   myfieldB    456
```

For some reason when I try to graph these in Grafana, or even to a select query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Some_Measurement WHERE "time" > now() - 60m
```

I get nothing back. It's almost as if it does not recognize the timestamps as timestamps. I have a feeling this might be because I'm writing these from my source as strings, but I have no idea what the correct data type should be. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This is by default in the terminal query, but you can change this by the below command :

[image]

```
precision rfc3339
```

After applying the above command it gives the properly formatted time in the select commands

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for respondign, but that does not answer my question. I need to know why its not accepting my timestamps as valid.

Comment: There is no aggregate function name now influx, time() functio function is there which u can used